# Sonar Qube Error while Configuring in Eclipse

Tags: sonarqube

Tried to configure SonarQube in Eclipse . Getting "SonarQube server 4.1.1 is not supported. Minimal supported version is 4.2" this error.

Comment: So... what is the question ?

Comment: In the Eclipse mars (4.2.1) i installed sonarQube 3.5 , and while configuring  server (Window/preferences/sonarQube/servers/add)  am getting this error "SonarQube server 4.1.1 at http://ipdetails:9001 is not supported. Minimal supported version is 4.2 "

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use earlier version of eclipse or upgrade the sonarqube version to 4.2 to use it with eclipse mars.

Eclipse Juno should be working with 3.4 to 4.1 sonarqube
Older versions of sonarqube can accessed only through Helios and Indigo.

The sonar plugin has now been deprecated and replaced by SonarLint for sonarqube 5.2+ versions.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with Eclipse Juno (Juno Service Release 2) and 4.1 sonar qube . Still am getting the same error :(

Comment: I tried with Eclipse Juno (Juno Service Release 1) . It worked . Thank u very much :)

Comment: could you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/314893) the answer.